# Where the hell is my Hydreigon?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

My *Pokémon White* cartridge has Hydreigon as Caught, which means that at one point I had one. It's not there any more, and I kind of need it.

- I can't find it in any of my PC boxes, or in my current party.
- It's not at the daycare.
- I didn't trade it. I only have one other cart and it only has Hydreigon as Seen, not Caught, so it can't be there.
- I didn't release it. I never release Pokémon.
- It can't have evolved. Hydreigon is the final evolution of its line.
- I don't think I traded it to friends or online.
- I don't think there are any in-game trades that accept Hydreigon, but I could be wrong.
- It's not tucked in to the Dream World.
- It's not in the Battle Box.

Where the hell could it be?

Comment: Have you checked your Battle Box?

Comment: Not there either.

Answer (score 1):

The only real option is that you traded it online/with a friend and don't remember. You've checked everywhere in-game that I know of, and there aren't in-game trades for it, so the only option is that it's not on your cartridge.

It sucks, but you've traded it away. Catching a new one and hoping you got something good for your Hydreigon is your only real option.